# AD LastLogin property updating when computer is turned on without anyone logging in

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been making a simple backup usage report via a powershell script that queries all our domain controllers for the `LastLogin` property of each computer, then filter those results so that each PC only has the most recent entry. I have noticed that the property is updating when a computer is turned on regardless of whether or not someone logs in. It also seems to be updating at least once an hour when the machine is just sitting on.  I cannot find any documentation that hints to this being the effect they want.

I am using `LastLoging` instead of `LastLoginTimeStamp` because `LastLoginTimestamp` only updates if it has not been logged in within the last 14 days(or whatever we set the value to). I am not sure if the `LastLoginTimeStamp` has the same issue where computers being on change that property.

Anyone else have this issue or any hints as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lastLogon` attribute is talking about the last logon time of the **computer account** itself, but not about last logon time of any users on this computer.

Any services running as the LocalSystem or NetworkService are actually using the computer account when accessing any network resources. So it's quite often the computer account will be authenticated.

Comment: Oh alright, that makes sense. I was just under the impression it was the last time the computer had a User log into it.

Answer (score 0):

I could very easily be wrong about this but my understanding of the LastLogin property is that it reflects the last time the computer contacted the network, not the last time a user logs into it.  I would probably use Group Policy to have it run a quick batch file on user log in with something like:

```
echo %computername%, %date%, %time% >> "\\someserver\somefile.csv"
```

This way it only records the date and time of the last time a user logs into it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That seems like a nice alternative and I being a csv would still work with my current script and excel macros to make the information nice looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon()
{
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
$time = 0
$exportFilePath = "c:\lastLogon.csv"
$columns = "name,username,datetime"

Out-File -filepath $exportFilePath -force -InputObject $columns

foreach($user in $users)
{
foreach($dc in $dcs)
{ 
  $hostname = $dc.HostName
  $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName | Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon

  if($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) 
  {
    $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
  }
}

$dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
$row = $user.Name+","+$user.SamAccountName+","+$dt

Out-File -filepath $exportFilePath -append -noclobber -InputObject $row

$time = 0
}
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

This script should return the info you need.
See [PowerShell: Get Last Logon for All Users Across All Domain Controllers](https://www.interworks.com/blogs/trhymer/2014/01/22/powershell-get-last-logon-all-users-across-all-domain-controllers) for more details.